# Leaflet: get layer instance from SVG path element

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet, element, layer

I have a map in leaflet.
Having a SVG element of a polyline ( a path node ) i need to get the instance of layer associated to it.

I've tried getting the _leaflet_id but it is not present in the object map._layers

Any suggestion?

Comment: I've just discovered that the _leaflet_id in the path element is equal to the id key in the layers object plus one (+1). I don't know if it is a bug or something wrong in my configuration, anyway I have noticed no problems in the behaviour of leaflet. I'm using the 1.4.0 version

Comment: the question does not really make sense to me, you mean iterate map layers, e.g. via  `map.eachLayer`  and find polyline?  . @alexroat, could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: One thing is the SVG element "path" which is rendered, another thing is the polyline object that is a simple javascript object created by L.polyline(...) and when is added to a map or a layergroup is rendered. I was looking a way to get the polyline object which define the "path" elements in order to bind events on SVG not using the leaflet events binding system but for example using another method (vanilla js , jquery).